# Using Tor browser and Chrome/Firefox simultaneously

Tags: anonymity, firefox, chrome

So, let's say that I got interested in keeping myself anonymous a little to late. But I installed Tor and have some questions:

If I use two web browsers - Tor Browser and Chrome/Firefox - can my activity in Tor Browser be connected with my activity in Chrome/Firefox?

I know that there's a bunch of information on me as I have a Google account connected to the browser, the phone so they have EVERYTHING on me. But I'm interested if my activity in the two browser can be connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both a browser with a direct connection to the internet and a Tor enabled browser and still have your anonymity protected. These two browser doesn't care about each others existence and stores their configuration files and settings at different places.

There are [risks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38316/tor-and-regular-browser-side-by-side-does-that-make-sense) though, especially with the QUANTUMCOOKIES and timing-based attacks, you might be putting yourself at risk.

Comment: Temper that with a possibly minor issue: Firefox today asked permission to copy bookmarks and other things from Safari.  I've been using Firefox for years and it hasn't done that.  Possible this is connected to my recent use of Tor Browser?

Comment: @WGroleau, I notice in one of your posts on a [different thread](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7318/where-is-the-profile) that you deleted your Firefox profile directory. I suspect that this could be the cause of your being asked to re-import your bookmarks from Safari.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe.  I don't remember which I did first.

Answer (score 0):

This is my tutorial that using Chrome/Opera with tor https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCwj5b_Mvf8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: The OP is concerned with running the Tor Browser Bundle and another browser simultaneously. It's not about running Chrome through Tor, which is what the video in the link is describing.

Comment: Please don't include link-only answers either. Explaining, at least the basics, in your answer is much more helpful to users.